# Django simple user session

Tags: python, django, templates, session

I just want a simple django user session auth  . Log in , user data , logout . Also to test sessions in templates. Code:

```
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username','')
    password = request.POST.get('password','')
    user = auth.authenticate(username = username, password = password)

    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/auth_view')
     else:
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/invalid')


def loggedin(request):
    request.session['username'] = request.user.username //( tried this)<----------
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',
                             { 'username' : request.user.username})

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)          
    (kill the session)                                                 <-----------
    return render_to_response('logout.html')
```

base template(all templates extend this):
...

```
  <div id="rightsidebar">
        {% block rightsidebar %}

            {% if request.session.username != Null %} // (tried this) <-----------
                 Loggedin
            {% else %}
                Not Loggedin
            {% endif %}


            {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}This is the content area{% endblock %}
```

...

Comment: Missing an important part: What's the question?

Comment: actually there is none. I just want help with the code.Its a request for code. :)

Comment: Why would you need to store the username in the session dict, when it is already available in the `request.user` object? Why wouldn't you just use that `user` object directly in the template?

Comment: cause i cant access it from templates. i tried responding with my_data = {} to the base.html. but it works only when i was in that specific view. In php i used to auth users with session and it was simply. I cant figure it out in django python. I cant understand user authentiction in django and i have studied all the documentations.

Comment: But randomly inserting stuff into the session dict doesn't help if you're accessing that through the same parent object - `request` - that you would the username. The issue is, of course, that you're not sending `request` to the template in the first place. `render(request, template_name, context)` will do that for you, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render]).

Comment: Everyone is suggesting me to do that i have tried to. It works perfectly but only fot that particular view. all templates extend the base.html but the only one view fuction returns(sends) that data to the template. I want my rightside bar ,that is extended by all templates, to find the user in all urls. When user is logged in should always see in the rightside bar: Loggen in etc. In all urls.

Comment: Its so simply to explain and so difficult to understand how to do it.this is 3rd post for this matter. Answered by more than 20 people and none understands me. I seems that i am wrong , i am asking for something simple BUT i  can't think "django".

Answer (score 0):

So as people have suggested, Django authentication is already built in you don't need sessionstate for that.  You should be able to access your logged in users through your base.html page as you have described.

In your template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
user is logged in
{% else %}
user is NOT logged in
{% endif %}
```

You need to make sure all your views where you are having a problem are using RequestContext

In your view

```
def your_view(request):
    return render_to_response('my_template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Don't use `render_to_response`. Use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) and you will get the RequestContext for free.

Comment: Done that , been there. Told you this only works for one view. The view that sends that context to the template . case of other urls---> other views wont work. I understand that i dont need to use sessions in django auth for users. Explain to me if there is way so do what i need. Of course there is no way to return this in all views off the app. Its just stupid. Maybe the problem is templates. How to solve that? This might be the CORRECT QUESTION for this post.